# My Scrollbar is scrolling only two texts of buttons right, instead of three

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a scrollbar which can scroll multiple texts of Buttons. I've created three texts, but it is only working with two of them instead of all of them. The text of the middle isn't moving right. How could I solve it?

THIS IS THE CODE:

```
from tkinter import *
words = ['way', 'day', 'man', 'dog', 'eye', 'job', 'end', 'law', 'car', 'kid', 'art', 'war'
     , 'guy', 'air', 'gay', 'time', 'year', 'life', 'hand', 'part', 'case', 'week', 'work',
     'home', 'room', 'area', 'fact', 'book', 'word', 'side', 'kind', 'head', 'hour',
     'game', 'line', 'city', 'name', 'team', 'idea', 'body', 'back', 'face', 'door',
     'girl', 'thing', 'woman', 'child', 'world', 'state', 'group', 'place', 'night',
     'point', 'water', 'money', 'story', 'month', 'right', 'study', 'issue', 'house',
     'power', 'level', 'water', 'party', 'force',  'river',  'piano', 'people', 'school', 'family', 'system',
     'number', 'mother', 'friend', 'guitar', 'valley', 'stream', 'father', 'member', 'minute', 'parent', 'others',
     'office', 'forest', 'health', 'person', 'result', 'change', 'reason', 'moment', 'student',
     'country', 'problem', 'company', 'program', 'service', 'history', 'science', 'morning',
     'teacher', 'question', 'business', 'mountain', 'religion', 'research','saxophone', 'community', 'president',
     'education', 'government']


class Words(object):
    def __init__(self, toplevel):

        toplevel.title('Morse Trainer')
        toplevel.geometry('800x600')
        toplevel.configure(background='#8352ab')
        label_font = ('Arial', 14, 'bold')
        self.top = toplevel
        self.label_frame = Frame(toplevel, bg='#673373', padx=351)
        self.label_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label = Label(self.label_frame, text='Select Word', fg='white', bg='#673373', 
        font=label_font, pady=22)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)


    # Buttons Frame
        self.bt_f = Frame(toplevel, bg='#8352ab')
        self.bt_f.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.text = Text(self.bt_f, wrap='none')
        self.text2 = Text(self.bt_f, wrap='none')
        self.text3 = Text(self.bt_f, wrap='none')
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.bt_f, command=self.text.yview)

        self.scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, expand=False)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscroll1, width=32,height=33, bg='#BE74CF')
        self.text2.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscroll2, width=31,height=33, bg='#BE74CF')
        self.text3.configure(yscrollcommand=self.yscroll3, width=31,height=33, bg='#BE74CF')
        self.text.pack(fill="both", expand=False, side=LEFT)
        self.text2.pack(fill="both", expand=False, side=LEFT)
        self.text3.pack(fill="both", expand=False, side=LEFT)

        print(len(words)-1)
        cont = -1
        for m in words:
            cont+=1
            self.groove = Button(self.bt_f, bg='#BE74CF', fg='black',
                                  font=label_font, highlightbackground='red', highlightcolor='red',
                                  activebackground='white', highlightthickness=1, text=m, width=20)
            if cont <37:
                self.text.window_create("end", window=self.groove)
                self.text.insert("end", "\n")
            elif cont < 74 and cont>36:
                self.text2.window_create("end", window=self.groove)
                self.text2.insert("end", "\n")
            else:
                self.text3.window_create("end", window=self.groove)
                self.text3.insert("end", "\n")
        self.text.configure(state="disabled")
        self.text2.configure(state="disabled")
        self.text3.configure(state="disabled")

    def yscroll1(self, *args):
        if self.text2.yview() != self.text.yview() and self.text3.yview()!= self.text.yview():
            self.text3.yview_moveto(args[0])
        self.scrollbar.set(*args)

    def yscroll2(self, *args):
        if self.text.yview() != self.text2.yview()and self.text3.yview()!= self.text2.yview():
            self.text3.yview_moveto(args[0])
        self.scrollbar.set(*args)
    def yscroll3(self, *args):
        if self.text.yview() != self.text3.yview()and self.text2.yview()!= self.text3.yview():

            self.text2.yview_moveto(args[0])

        self.scrollbar.set(*args)

    def yview(self, *args):
        self.text.yview(*args)
        self.text2.yview(*args)

   
window = Tk()
Words(window)
window.mainloop()
```

How you can see running it, the middle text is scrolling down, but it's not scrolling up. What is the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the `command` attribute of the scrollbar to call a function that scrolls all three windows. You seem to have a function that scrolls two out of three, but you aren't using it.

First, change the scrollbar command to look like this:

```
self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.bt_f, command=self.yview)
```

Next, modify the `yview` method to scroll all three windows:

```
def yview(self, *args):
    self.text.yview(*args)
    self.text2.yview(*args)
    self.text3.yview(*args)
```